# Snowflake SQL Counting and Summing from Another Table based on Matching Value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do an SQL query in snowflake to count up values from a different table based on a value from the first table. For example, I find a value that matches in table1 and table2, and I count the rows that match it from table 2.

When I attempt to do this, the query runs but the resulting data is incorrectly counting. It looks as if it is doing some sort of odd breakout/cumulative counting.
I've tried reading examples and googling for examples like this but what's interesting is in non-snowflake SQL, the examples I've seen do not need to "group by" the count I'm trying to select.

In snowflake it gives me an error unless I group the (select count(*) from...
But doing this seems to return a result that is over counting/summing the value by a lot, when I remove that (select count(*)... row and the group by, it does everything else correctly so I'm guessing there's something specifically wrong there.

```sql
select 
    "naming_db"."public"."username".name as "Name",
    "naming_db"."public"."addresses".address as "Address",
    count(*) as "Shoe Count",
    (select count(*) from "data_db"."records"."orderID" where 
    "data_db"."records"."orderID".ID = "data_db"."records"."userinfo".ID) as "Orders",
    sum("data_db"."records"."userinfo".revenue) as "Spend"
from "data_db"."records"."userinfo"
    join "naming_db"."public"."username" on "naming_db"."public"."username".name = "data_db"."records"."userinfo".nameid
    join "naming_db"."public"."addresses" on "naming_db"."public"."addresses".address = "data_db"."records"."userinfo".addressid
    full join "data_db"."records"."orderID" on "data_db"."records"."userinfo".ID = "data_db"."records"."orderID".ID
group by 1,2,4
```

The (select count(*) from... line I think is the issue but I can't seem to figure out how to write it in a way that would make the query run and return the results I want.

**Just edited the query to make more sense. Was trying to obfuscate some of the info there but I realized it's too confusing sorry!**

Here's the results that I would like. I get this when I remove the "Orders" line - the one that is (select count(*) from...

[Correct but missing Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kzrh.png)

Here's the results that I'm getting when I add in that line for "Orders":
[Incorrect summing and breaks out more rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F3pF.png)

Comment: select distinct count(*) , this might help you.

Comment: You should say something about what tables 1-3 contain and how they are related.  That info is needed to make sure you get a correct solution.

Comment: Joining twice to `table1` on two different columns is highly suspicious.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sorry about that. I realized that it was more confusing than I'd like when I tried to obfuscate some of the info but I've revised it to better show. Let me know if it makes sense now! I also added in examples of the results.

Comment: Your description is better now, but still lacks detail.  Specifically, userinfo is unclear:  does it contain one record per user, or is it an order table?  If it is an order table, maybe then orderID are the order details?  What are the unique keys of the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub-select is a correlated sub-query which snow has limited support for. So if you pivot to a CTE which does the count for all `ID`'s then join to that you should get what you are asking for..

```
WITH order_counts AS (
    SELECT ID, count(*) as count data_db.records.orderID group by 1
)
select 
    un.name as Name,
    a.address as Address,
    count(*) as Shoe Count,
    oc.count as Orders,
    sum(ui.revenue) as Spend
from data_db.records.userinfo as ui
join naming_db.public.username as un
    on un.name = ui.nameid
join naming_db.public.addresses as a
    on a.address = ui.addressid
left join order_counts as oc
    on ui.ID = oc.ID
group by 1,2,4
```

I also inserted some aliases so the SQL was more readable.

Comment: This got me 99% of the way there! I realized there was another ID that should have been used instead and that was the final piece haha. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

After you rearranged the query, it looks like you have:

1. `userinfo` is the **User** table that contains one line per user and also has an accumulated revenue amount per user
2. `orderID` is the **Order** table with quantities per customer per product
3. `username` and `addresses` are only used to display the user contact info (unimportant).

It is still hard to understand what your aggregations should show, so I've tried to guess:

1. **Shoe count** is out in the blue in your revised query.  It counts the number of accumulated lines per user, which is now the number of order lines.  Shoe data used to be in the query, but you removed it, so *Shoe Count* makes no sense now.
2. **Orders** most likely is the total number of orders per user, also the number of lines in the order table for that user.  But there is no difference to *Shoe Count*, which makes me wonder why.
3. **Spend** is the revenue per user.

The use of a `FULL JOIN` is confusing.  It indicates that some orders are for non-registered users - not existing in the `userinfo` table.  This doesn't make sense to me.  Your examples indicates that all orders are from users in `userinfo`, so there should be no need for a `FULL JOIN`.
Why do you need it?

The solution should be really simple.  Please advise me if I didn't understand your requirements:

```
SELECT
  ANY_VALUE(n.name) AS "Name",
  ANY_VALUE(a.address) AS "Address",
  COUNT(*) AS "Shoe Count", 
  COUNT(o.ID) AS "Orders",
  ANY_VALUE(u.revenue) AS "Spend"
FROM "data_db"."records"."userinfo" u
INNER JOIN "naming_db"."public"."username" n ON n.name = u.nameid
INNER JOIN "naming_db"."public"."addresses" a ON a.address = u.addressid
INNER JOIN "data_db"."records"."orderID" o ON o.ID = u.ID
GROUP BY u.ID
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I've updated the query to be more clear. I want to count all the orderIDs based on the matching ID found from another table. I hope I'm phrasing that properly haha. I attached example screenshots of the results and what I'm hoping to achieve. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You are still not as specific as possible, maybe because you want to hide the details of your real case.  You say "another table", but not which.  From your latest example we can assume you mean the userinfo table.

I suspect at least part of your problem comes from wanting to show different aggregations where some of the numbers have been duplicated by the table joins resulting in incorrect high numbers.  But this can be remedied by using ANY_VALUE() if there is only a single number in the base table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sum()` instead of using `subquery` on your `column` Shoes.

```
select 
    "table1".name as "Name",
    "table1".address as "Address",
    count(*) as "Counts",
    sum(case when coalesce("table3".shoeID, 0) != 0 then 1 else 0 end) as "Shoes",
    sum("table2".shoecount) as "Number of Shoes"
from "table2"
join "table1" on "table1".name = "table2".name
join "table1" on "table1".Address = "table2".Address
full join "table3" on "table3".shoeID = "table2".shoeID
group by 1,2,4
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm not too sure how coalesce works. It's throwing an error because the shoeID isn't a numeric value - it's alphanumeric, so I'm guessing it has to do with the logic after? But also I think it wouldn't sum the count of shoes based on the ID found in the other table. Appreciate the help!